# Parameter name not recognised with @ sign

Tags: postgresql, npgsql

I have a function defined as

```
FUNCTION user_salt_get("@username" character varying)
```

I call this from C# code with the following:

```
            using (NpgsqlConnection sqlConn = new NpgsqlConnection(_conn))
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                using (NpgsqlCommand sqlCmd = new NpgsqlCommand("user_salt_get", sqlConn))
                {
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)).Value = username;
                    salt = (string)(sqlCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
                sqlConn.Close();
            }
```

Whereas this worked in previous versions I am now getting the error :

```
42883: function user_salt_get(username := character varying) does not exist
```

It seems if I amend my code to :

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("@@username", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar)).Value = username;
```

It seems the @ sign is causing some issues is there a way around this as most of our codebase uses parameters named this way?

Comment: Issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1215